# Nginx forward a URL to another URL:Port

Tags: apache, redirect, nginx

I have a server that's using nginx and httpd (vestaCP). I'm trying to get panel.domain.com to go to domain.com:8083. I can't use proxy pass as changing the URL screws up vestacp. So i'm just needing nginx to forward people to domain.com:8083 when they go to panel.domain.com.

I currently have:

```
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name panel.domain.com.au;
        return 301 https://domain.com.au:8083;
}
```

Comment: You need to enable ssl. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html)

Comment: Made no difference